# Node.js Can I force forever not to restart my app?

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm using forever to restart my node.js app.
Sometimes I want my app not to restart.

Is there a way for my app to tell `forever` "do not restart me this time"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want "do not restart me this time", you can run it with:
node app.js

And it will not restart this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

- RTM: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever
- Install Forever (of course): `npm install forever --save`
- Import it into your module: `require('forever');`
- Now you have access to the `forever` object: `forever.stopAll();`
- Bonus: want to kill Node a different way? `process.exit();`

---

(There's another package called `forever-monitor`, but this is only for watching events from a Forever instance.)